# Transforming a symbolic variable into a function

Tags: functions, replacement

I have a variable of the general form

```
variable = 
  Subscript[f, {a, b}] Subscript[f, {c, d}] + 
    Subscript[f, {a, c}] Subscript[f, {b, d}]
```

I would like to transform it something of the form:

```
f[x_, y_]:= x + y
variable[a_, b_, c_, d_] := f[a, b] f[c, d] + f[a, c] f[b, d]
```

After seeing some of the answers, perhaps I should pinpoint my problem, the variable I used here is just the general form of a long expression I got after some other calculations and eventualy a Series expansion, I tried to use replacement rules but got the next notice:
"SetDelayed: Tag SeriesData in (a lot of symbols) is Protected"

Will appreciate any help!

Answer (score 2):

First you must correct your definition of `f` to

```
f[x_, y_] := x + y
```

Then given

```
var =
  Subscript[f, {a, b}] Subscript[f, {c, d}] + 
    Subscript[f, {a, c}] Subscript[f, {b, d}];
```

you can write

```
 v[a_, b_, c_, d_] = var /. Subscript[f_, {u_, v_}] -> f[u, v];
```

Then

```
 v[a, b, c, d]
```

gives

> `(a + c) (b + d) + (a + b) (c + d)`

If really want use the name `var` to refer to `v`, you can write

```
var = v
```

making `var` an alias for `v`, but I don't recommend that because you will lose the original definition of `var`

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding your question, a replacement should do well.

```
variable = Subscript[f,{a,b}] Subscript[f,{c,d}] + Subscript[f,{a,c}] Subscript[f,{b,d}]
result = ReplaceAll[Subscript[f_,{x_,y_}] -> f[x,y]][variable]
```

For a more functional approach:

```
variable[a_,b_,c_,d_]:= Subscript[f,{a,b}] Subscript[f,{c,d}] + Subscript[f,{a,c}] Subscript[f,{b,d}]
g[a_,b_,c_,d_]:= variable[a,b,c,d]//ReplaceAll[Subscript[f_,{x_,y_}] -> f[x,y]]
```

Substitute any function of your choice for `f` using the following:

```
g[a,b,c,d] /. {f -> MyFunction}
```

Comment: Thank you for answering, but it doesn't work for me. I've been able to use a replacement rule to insert the required function in place of the symbolic variable, but haven't been able to assign the result to a new function of all the possible variables (a,b,c,d in my example).
I may add that "variable" is a result of a Series expansion from some initial result of another calculation

Comment: @GabyFleurov I just updated my answer, which should take into account your need for a function assignment. You'll need to use SetDelayed (`:=`) with `variable` in order to have `a,b,c,d` evaluated every time the symbol is used.

Comment: thanks,I'll check it out

Answer (score 1):

**Update:** For more general inputs:

```
ClearAll[makeFunction]
makeFunction[v_] := Module[{vars = Sort@DeleteDuplicates@
       Flatten@Cases[v, Subscript[_, x_] :> x, {0, Infinity}]},
       v /. Subscript -> (# @@ #2 &) /. Thread[vars -> {##}]] &
```

Examples:

```
variable = Subscript[f, {a, b}] Subscript[f, {c, d}] + 
   Subscript[f, {a, c}] Subscript[f, {b, d}];
variable2 = Subscript[f1, {a, b, c}] + Subscript[f2, {c, d, e}] + 
   Subscript[f3, {e, f, g}] Subscript[f4, {g, h, i}];
variable3 = Subscript[f1, {a, b, c}] + Subscript[f2, {c, d, e}] + 
   Subscript[f3, {e, f, g}] Subscript[f4, {g, h, i}]^2;

Column[{variable, makeFunction[variable][a, b, c, d]}]
```

> [image]

```
Column[{variable2, makeFunction[variable2] @@ (Symbol["x" <> ToString[#]] & /@ Range[9])}]
```

> [image]

```
Column[{variable2, makeFunction[variable2] @@ Range[9]}]
```

> [image]

```
Column[{variable3, makeFunction[variable3] @@ Range[9]}]
```

> [image]

**Original answer:**

```
ClearAll[vF]
vF[w_, x_, y_, z_] := variable /. Subscript->(# @@ #2 &) /. 
      Thread[{a, b, c, d} -> {w, x, y, z}]

vF[a, b, c, d]
```

> f[a, c] f[b, d] + f[a, b] f[c, d]

```
vF[u, v, w, x]
```

> f[u, w] f[v, x] + f[u, v] f[w, x]

```
vF[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

> f[1, 3] f[2, 4] + f[1, 2] f[3, 4]

If `f` is pre-defined:

```
f[x_, y_] := x + y;
vF[a, b, c, d]
```

> (a + c) (b + d) + (a + b) (c + d)

```
vF[u, v, w, x]
```

> (u + w) (v + x) + (u + v) (w + x)

```
vF[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

> 45

Comment: thanks,
would you care to explain the syntax in   
     Subscript->(#@@#2&)?
Also, I think you missed a closing } in the Thread function, is it after the d?

Comment: @GabyFleurov, `Subscript->(#@@#2&)` is another way of writing `Subscript[a_,b_] :> a[b])`.  when it is fed two arguments (`f` and `{x,y}` , say) , the pure function `#@@#2&`   produces `f@@{x,y}` ( which is `f[x,y]`).